# Memory error in function "cudaMallocPitch"

Tags: cuda

```
#define mas_len 10000
#define pod_mas_len 100
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void)//GPU
{
    FILE* file;
    char** lines_host = (char**)malloc(mas_len * sizeof(char*));
 
    BYTE** buf = (BYTE**)malloc(mas_len * sizeof(BYTE*));
    cudaError_t a, b, c;
    char* lines_device;
    size_t pitch;
    a = cudaMallocPitch((char**)&lines_device, &pitch, 10 * sizeof(char), 10);
    printf(cudaGetErrorString(a));
 
    BYTE* buf_gpu;
    size_t pitch2;
    b = cudaMallocPitch((char**)&buf_gpu, &pitch2, pod_mas_len * sizeof(char), mas_len);
    printf(cudaGetErrorString(b));
 
    file = fopen("passwords.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) exit(-1);
 
    while (!feof(file)) {
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas_len && !feof(file); i++) {
            lines_host[i] = (char*)calloc(100, sizeof(char));
            fgets(lines_host[i], 100, file);
            lines_host[i][strcspn(lines_host[i], "\n")] = '\0';
            num++;
        }
        c = cudaMemcpy2D(lines_device, pitch, lines_host, pod_mas_len * sizeof(char), pod_mas_len * sizeof(char), mas_len, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        printf(cudaGetErrorString(c));
        cudaMemcpy2D(buf_gpu, pitch2, buf, pod_mas_len * sizeof(char), pod_mas_len * sizeof(char), mas_len, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
......
}
```

In debugger mode, after executing the cudaMallocPitch function, it writes that a  has occurred. The error in the code occurs when calling the cudaMemcpy2D function, as an attempt is made to send incorrect data to an unknown address. I do not know how to deal with this.

Have you ever had such an error and if so, how did you deal with it?

Comment: `cudaMemcpy2D`, like all CUDA `cudaMemcpy` functions, requires contiguous allocations.  `lines_host` does not represent a contiguous allocation.  You cannot copy that way.  This topic is covered in many posts here on the `cuda` SO tag.    There are or should be no runtime errors associated with either of the 2 `cudaMallocPitch` calls.